# Spring Boot apps. SecurityContextHolder vs. HttpSession

Tags: java, spring-mvc, jakarta-ee, spring-boot, java-ee-7

In Web app. is so common to store the user details in the session, But if in Spring Boot you configure you `SecurityConfig` class as follows:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {                  

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth
            .userDetailsService(userSecurityService)
           .passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    }
...
}
```

and

```
@Service
public class UserSecurityService implements UserDetailsService {

    /** The application logger */
    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(UserSecurityService.class);

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String email) throws UsernameNotFoundException {

        LOG.info("Searching user with email: " + email);

        User user = userRepository.findByEmail(email);

        if (null == user) {
            LOG.warn("Username {} not found", email);
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException("Username " + email + " not found");
        }
        return user;
    }
}
```

and

```
public class User implements Serializable, UserDetails {
..
}
```

then you can grap all the info from the logged user using always

```
User user = (User)SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal()
```

so.. storing the user info in the `HttpSession` is a bad practice, old practice or I miss something ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Spring Security is a security framework and can be used in both web and standalone applications. The `SecurityContextHolder` provides a unified way of obtaining the `SecurityContext` and in the end the `User`.

When using Spring Security in a web application the storage of the `SecurityContext` is delegated to the `SecurityContextRepository` and the default implementation used is the `HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository` so in the end it still stores it in the `HttpSession` but you could also create your own implementation and store it else where (a database, Redis, etc.).

In short the `SecurityContextHolder` is thus a unified way to get the `SecurityContext` used by Spring Security without you having to know in all the places how/where it is stored.